# Binance API : How i get Price Digits and Lots size Digits

Tags: binance

How I am getting Price digits and Lots digits from Binance API. I am using https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo?symbol=LTCUSDT

But i where i get this value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the decimal information from `exchange_info` API:

- spot: [/api/v3/exchangeInfo](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#exchange-information)
- usd-futures: [/fapi/v1/exchangeInfo](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#exchange-information)
- coin-futures: [/dapi/v1/exchangeInfo](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/delivery/en/#exchange-information)

For example, exchange info API will return a json object containing a key `symbols`, which leads to a list of objects of trading rules and symbol information.

For each symbol information, there is `quoteAssetPrecision` and `baseAssetPrecision` to indicate the decimal precision.

Also, there is a `filter` key for each symbol. You can find `tickSize` and `stepSize` there.